# How can I filter the results of a query using SQLite in a Windows Store Application?

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I want to retrieve only the first three results of a query and show them in a ListView, but how can I filter my results?

This is my code:

```
var dbpath = Path.Combine(Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path, "guessndraw.db");
using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(dbpath))
{
    ListaParole.ItemsSource = db.Table<wordlist_it>();
}
```

wordlist_it class:

```
public class wordlist_it
{
    public string word { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}",word);
    }
}
```

In this way, it gives me ALL the records of the table, but I just want the first 3 records.
Can you explain me how to set a query in a windows store application using c# and sqlite? Thank you :)

Comment: What you mean saying first. Have you any order in your table?

Comment: I mean something like "SELECT word FROM wordlist LIMIT 3"

Comment: and you really don't care which of three?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is from memory, but you could try:

```
ListaParole.ItemsSource = db.Table<wordlist_it>().Take(3);
```

Comment: Can you also explain me how to use Where() clause? :\

Comment: To start, check out http://codefoster.com/post/2012/05/01/A-Primer-on-LINQ-and-Lambda.aspx  Also take a look at the 101 linq examples at the bottom of the article.  A sample lambda query for your code above would be: var words = db.Table<wordlist_it>().Where(w => w.word.StartsWith('a');

Comment: I think I'm missing a closing paren in the lambda expression above. It should be: var words = db.Table<wordlist_it>().Where(w => w.word.StartsWith('a'));

Comment: Thanks, you made my day! :D It gave me an error because i had to use quotes instead of single quote, so it's: 
ListaParole.ItemsSource = db.Table<wordlist_it>().Where(w => w.word.StartsWith("a")); 
Thanks again :)